# Should I have front and back end helper classes?

Tags: joomla-3.x

Is it just a matter of preference or are there some good reasons to create and use separate helper classes for the front and back end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the same for both in order not to repeat the same code twice,
if of course the helper class does not do something that a root should only do  (and this is a way I go with helper classes).